# How to print the number of data entries inside a variable in R?

Tags: r, variables

I know this is probably a very simple question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere online. I am trying to print just the number of data points inside of a variable that I created but I can't figure out how.

I tried using `summary()` or `num()` or `n()` but I am really just making stuff up here and cannot seem to figure it out at all.

For my specific example I have a data set on peoples heights, age, weight, gender, stuff like that.
 I used

```
one_sd_weight <- cdc$weight[abs(cdc$weight - mean(cdc$weight)) <= sd(cdc$weight)]
```

to determine how many of the weights fall within one standard deviation of the mean. After I do this, I can see that on the right side it created a new variable called one_sd_weight that contains 14152 out of the original 20000 entries. How do I print the number 14152 as a variable? For the work I am doing I need to create a new variable that just contains one number, 14152 or whatever number is produced when I run the code above. For example, I need to create

```
n_one_sd <- 14152
```

without typing in 14152, instead typing some function that grabs the number of entries in one_sd_weight.

I have tried things like summary() and n() but only receive error messages in return. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I also don't know how to make the code look like code on this website so please ignore the formatting of the code

Comment: `length(one_sd_weight)`

Comment: (put four spaces ahead of each line of code to make it look like code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n_one_sd <- length(one_sd_weight)
```

You're looking for `length` (in case of a vector) or `nrow` in case of a matrix/data.frame.

Or you can use `NROW()` for both, that should work too.

Comment: Thank you so much, length() was exactly what I needed. I knew it was something super easy I just couldn't figure it out!